# Fail2ban not listening on correct ports

Tags: debian, iptables, fail2ban

Fail2ban was working but I went to pentest my server and for whatever reason, the Apache2 jails are not working.  I checked IPTables with iptables -S and there are 9 entries for `-A input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-default` even though I have the ports specified as http and https in the jails.conf

I have tried going into the jails.conf again and changing http,https to 80,443 and the same thing happens. I have no idea why fail2ban is adding iptables entries for port 22 on every type of jail but nothing I do seems to fix this.

I'm on debian 9 if that matters to anyone trying to help me.

EDIT: Config file

```
[INCLUDES]
before = paths-debian.conf
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
ignorecommand =
bantime  = 600
findtime  = 600
maxretry = 5
backend = auto
usedns = warn
logencoding = auto
#enabled = true
filter = %(__name__)s
destemail = root@localhost
sender = fail2ban@localhost
mta = sendmail
protocol = tcp
chain = INPUT
port = 0:65535
fail2ban_agent = Fail2Ban/%(fail2ban_version)s
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
action_xarf = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             xarf-login-attack[service=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, port="%(port)s"]
action_cf_mwl = cloudflare[cfuser="%(cfemail)s", cftoken="%(cfapikey)s"]
                %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
action_blocklist_de  = blocklist_de[email="%(sender)s", service=%(filter)s, apikey="%(blocklist_de_apikey)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_badips = badips.py[category="%(__name__)s", banaction="%(banaction)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_badips_report = badips[category="%(__name__)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action = %(action_)s


[sshd]
enabled = true
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare

[sshd-ddos]
# This jail corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban.
# The mail-whois action send a notification e-mail with a whois request
# in the body.
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare

[apache-auth]
enabled = true
port    = 80,443
logpath = %(apache_error_log)s
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-badbots]
enabled  = true
port     = 80,443
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 1
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-noscript]

port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-overflows]
enabled  = true
port     = 80,443
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
maxretry = 2
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-nohome]
enabled  = true
port     = 80,443
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
maxretry = 2
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-botsearch]
enabled  = true
port     = 80,443
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
maxretry = 2
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-fakegooglebot]
enabled  = true
port     = 80,443
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
maxretry = 1
ignorecommand = %(ignorecommands_dir)s/apache-fakegooglebot <ip>
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-modsecurity]
enabled  = true
port     = 80,443
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
maxretry = 2
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare


[apache-shellshock]
enabled = true
port    = 80,443
logpath = %(apache_error_log)s
maxretry = 1
action  = iptables-multiport
          cloudflare
```

Comment: Please add your config files to the question.

Comment: I added the config file

Comment: Fail2ban does not listen at all...

Answer (score 0):

Port 22 is for SSH. It's normal for Fail2ban to ban multiple connection retries on that port. Nothing is wrong with this picture; it works correctly.

Comment: There should only be 2 rules for SSH, the rest should be for HTTP and HTTPS.  I have 2 port 22 based jails and 7 http and https based jails.  The reason why I even discovered this problem is because there IS something wrong and auth attempts do not result in a block.

Comment: If there are http (and s) jails means it works. Check the date when the jail happened if possible. The number is irrelevant. It depends on how many attempts/attacks have been.

Comment: If there is a jail for http it should be in iptables on port 80 otherwise it does not see the port 80 traffic.  If fail2ban is looking for attacks on port 80 but is getting forwarded traffic from port 22 then it does nothing.

Comment: What do you have that uses port 80 for authentication ? Who still uses that to try to authenticate ?

Comment: I have Apache HTTP Auth that uses port 443, everything on port 80 is redirected to 443 but I still want to have a rule for it anyways. I use the apache auth to password protect some parts of my site like certain reverse proxies and directories where I have file listings.  Again, the question is not asking if I should be using this but rather why it isnt working.  In addition to the auth not being protected further by fail2ban, the badbots and whatnot are not being blocked which is arguably a bigger problem.